# What is the titre of a sodium hydroxide-sulfuric acid titration experiment?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

So I did for my AS Level exam today a titration experiment, seeing how much sulfuric acid of (I think) about $0.100 - 0.200 \text{ mol dm}^{-3}$, which went in the burette, is needed to react with 0.1M sodium hydroxide, in the conical flask.

We lose a mark for every $0.10\text{ cm}^3$ we are off of the actual titre value that should be obtained by a professional, i.e. our chemistry teacher.

I obtained an average titre of $24.28\text{ cm}^3$

Does anyone know what the titre should be from experience or memory in the lab of this experiment?

I know this isn't a constructive question, so feel free to downvote - I just really want to know so that I'm taken off of the edge I'm sitting on!

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really an answer to your question. The problem is, there is many possible ways in which that lab might have been set up and there's no telling which one you had to sit, not to say that the concentration of sulfuric acid given to you might have been *any* concentration between 0.100 and 0.200 M.

Also, if you do AS Chemistry, you should also be able to calculate the volume range you should be able to get. With 0.1 M sulfuric acid and 0.1 sodium hydroxide, you expect to use a titre of 12.5 mL of acid against 25 mL of base, to 6.25 mL of 0.2 M acid against 25 mL of 0.1 M base.

Since your titre value seems so off by calculation, I guess that the concentration of the acid could have been about 0.5 M instead, but really, there is no telling.

See a sample marking scheme (I took one from [June 2010](http://papers.xtremepapers.com/CIE/Cambridge%20International%20O%20Level/Chemistry%20%285070%29/5070_s12_ms_32.pdf) and the syllabus doesn't seem to have changed for this May/June sitting):

> (a) Accuracy [8]
>
> For the two best titres give:
>
> - 4 marks for value within 0.2 cm^3 of supervisor
> - 2 marks for value within 0.3 cm^3 of supervisor
> - 1 marks for value within 0.4 cm^3 of supervisor
>
> Concordance [3]
>
> Give:
>
> - 3 marks if all the ticked values are within 0.2 cm^3
> - 2 marks if all the ticked values are within 0.3 cm^3
> - 1 marks if all the ticked values are within 0.4 cm^3
>
> Average [1]
>
> Give 1 mark if the candidate calculates a correct average (error not greater than 0.05) of all his ticked values.

The second and third mark allocations are really easy to get. As long as you get your readings close to each other and calculate the average titre correctly, you will get 4 marks. I'm not sure where you got this "you lose 1 mark for every 0.1 mL off the supervisor's titre value". As you can see, if you get 2 best titre values withinn 0.2 mL of the supervisors, you get full marks.